# exit from parent function when child return false

Tags: javascript

```
function parent(){
    child();
    alert("XXXX")
}

function child(){
    return false;
}
```

I want exit from parent function when child return false;

Comment: `if (!child()) return;` (Stack Overflow's [javascript tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has links to various JS tutorials.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check result child function and then do your action

```
function parent(){
    var result=child();
    if(result==false)
       return false;
    alert("XXXX")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
function parent(){
    if(!child()){
         return false;
    }
}
```